# Expanding Pic16f877a flash memory

Tags: microcontroller

I have been working on this project nd the code has gotten ao huge that the microcontroller's flash memory is full,so I want to know if there is any way i can connect an external eeprom or any memory device that can help me have more program memory..

Thanx in advanced!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The only 8-bit PICs that can use external program memory are high-end parts in the PIC18F series - all 64-pin or more.

If a substantial portion of your code size consists of text or other data (rather than actual code), you could store the data on an external SPI or I2C EEPROM.  This would be much slower than having the data internally, and less convenient to use - you'd have to manually send an address and then read bytes from the external chip, you couldn't just access the data as an array.

The 16F877 is a rather old chip - you can certainly find ones with more capacity these days.  A quick search on [Microchip's part selector](http://www.microchip.com/maps/microcontroller.aspx) turns up several 16F chips with twice the program memory, such as the 16F1789.  If you'd be willing to switch to the more powerful 18F series, you could double the program memory yet again - 18F4620, for example.